# What is responsible for mounting disks listed in fstab?

Tags: mount, fstab, scripts, init

What script/init process/whatever is responsible for reading fstab and calling mount, during the boot process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the upstart job configured in

```
/etc/init/mountall.conf
```

that in turn calls the ELF executable `/sbin/mountall`.

Answer (score 5):

It's the `mountall` executable which parses the `fstab` file and mounts (and checks if needed) all the partitions specified there.